# Error compiling bookmark

Tags: formatting, hyperref, compiling, bookmarks

When compiling my MWE I had problems with accentuation in my markers.

Why compile with LuaLaTeX the error occurs and with pdfLateX this does not happen?

[image]

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\hypersetup
{
    hidelinks, % Remove red boxes
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    pdfauthor={Brian Griffin},
    pdftitle={Wish it, Want it, Do it},
    pdfsubject={Self help},
    pdfkeywords={therapy,healing,chicken soup},
    pdfproducer={Penguin Publishing}
}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}
% Section numbers without prefix or the place for adding a prefix
% "Section".
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Informações}
\blindtext

\section{Conversa informal}

\blindtext

\chapter{Caracterização}
\blindtext

\chapter{Conhecimento criativo}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the `unicode` option at `hypersetup` and remove `inputenc` when compiling with `lualatex`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I succeeded. You can add as a answer and add some comments explaining why these errors occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Christian Hupfer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398146/error-compiling-bookmark?noredirect=1#comment990586_398146)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\hypersetup
{
    unicode,
    hidelinks, % Remove red boxes
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    pdfauthor={Brian Griffin},
    pdftitle={Wish it, Want it, Do it},
    pdfsubject={Self help},
    pdfkeywords={therapy,healing,chicken soup},
    pdfproducer={Penguin Publishing}
}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}
% Section numbers without prefix or the place for adding a prefix
% "Section".
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Informações}
\blindtext

\section{Conversa informal}

\blindtext

\chapter{Caracterização}
\blindtext

\chapter{Conhecimento criativo}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]